# Using the if statement in a loop to create a class in a data.set in R

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have seen several questions that are similar to mine, but none of those answers is helping me get this code straight.

I want to classify a data set according to a set of a statement using if() statement, making a loop so it can be applied to the whole dataset. Here is my code:

```
x100 <- c(100,100,85,90,100,75,65,55,95,90)
x20 <- c(100, 95, 60,52,45,36,47,50,90,85)
index <- x100 + x20
code <- data.frame(x100, x20, index)
code$class <-for (i in code){
                 if (x100 < 100 & x20 < 50) { "3"}
                 else if (x100 ==100 & x20 >=50){"2"} 
                 else (x100 == 100 & x20 == 100) "1"
                 }
```

I just recently started to work with R, sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
for(i in code) { ... }
```

iterates over the columns in your dataframe, not the rows.  Use `ifelse`

```
with(code, ifelse(x100 < 100 & x20 < 50, '3', ifelse(x100 ==100 & x20 >=50, '2', '1')))
```